# A common scenario for Business but no elegant way in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Here is my simple situation: Common for most business...

- Suppose that we have **Orders** which consist of **Items.**[ Praent-Child]
- There is   2 user in the System: UserA and UserB
- UserA create an Order which has 3 items in it. And save it to database.
- Meanwhile UserB open the Order saved just before by UserA  to read Items of Order.
- Then UserA delete Item 1  from Orders and save it. Everything is OK
- Finally UserB delete item 3 and try to save...

And NHibernate gives "StaleObjectStateException"...

So how to handle this situation so that İtem1 and Item3 deleted and we got no "StaleObjectStateException"... with NHibernate?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should catch the exception and let the user know that the item was already updated by someone else, reload the entity from database and let the user decide what to do after checking the new data.

You could also you a pesimistic lock if you don't want let users to edit the same entity at the same time.

Check [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions) to get more info about concurrency control strategies.

[This](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency) post from Ayende Rahien is a very good reference too.

Comment: Pesimistick lock does not prevent ""StaleObjectStateException".

Comment: @Novalis: How's that? if you use it well, it should work since it set a lock over the record so no one else can do anything with it until the lock is released.

Comment: Well, follow my scenario...And you will get "StaleObjectStateException"... Ayende Rahien paper also says you can get this exception...

Comment: @Novalis: you'll get a timeout exception if you can't get the lock but not a StaleObjectStateException. Sorry but I don't see where Ayende says thay you could get it.

Comment: "As you can probably guess, if the version doesn’t match, we will get StaleObjectException." at your link to Ayende Post...In my scenario version does not match...

Comment: @Novalis: you'd get it for optimistic lock, but not for pesimistic lock. That sentense is in relation to optimistic lock `Setting optimistic-lock to all would result in... As you can probably guess, if the version doesn’t match, we will get StaleObjectException`